# How can I write a program to dispart the audio and video track from .3gp file?

Tags: video, 3gp, amr

I want to write a program that dispart the audio and video track from .3gp file.

(The format of video track is h.263 and audio is AMR. The data is generated from Android.)

A lot of information had been surveyed from internet but I still can not figure how to do it.

At first, I found out that the header of h.263 and AMR are 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 00 and 0x23, 0x21, 0x41, 0x4D, 0x52, 0x0A , respectively.

Howevey, I can not find the header from .3gp file.

Does someone can help me?

Comment: Best is to use some tool for this. FFMPEG, or VirtualDub. Doom9.org should have all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) to demux the .3gp file.  Don't try to do this yourself from scratch...it's a huge task to parse a media file to the degree required to demux the audio and video.  Literally months.

There are different ways to do this, but as leppie says, Doom9 is the authoritative source.  Check it out.  [Google: ffmpeg demux 3gp site:doom9.org](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ffmpeg+demux#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=ffmpeg+demux+3gp+site%3adoom9.org&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=ef34c9a9ed856910)